# How do I json_decode() this?

Tags: php, json

How can I `json_decode()` result of `file_get_contents`?

Here is my code.

```
$resp = file_get_contents('https://auth.login.yahoo.co.jp/yconnect/v1/token', false, $context);

echo "check1 <br />";
var_dump($resp);

$json = json_decode($resp);

echo "check2 <br />";
var_dump($json);
echo $json['access_token'];
```

The result is here

> check1 
>   string(744) "{"access_token":"j9MqiEM.lKjepCGMFdKufPw1UBK_gAlG6qFxvMxHJwbopXfo9LpLUyT1z.YxwFBSydvVSMOqzVI4fX_ZVLVROlNf7ARr08s2tkFMb5_TNq.wp1MmoQm3wJaqF9gxpeQbEz4GYuGJSbDKJTw8LA_XoBNcEbL0ZDeozFEgYxII8gqi_Nfi7UhM5bd7gqV6Sp17rCECQAauZj_jJa6jyADS3me3UYxIKJB2tCJpRM.xCzVhjRWEZPqNiUI5NikXRANrSiTyn_6Z72u2ptW3vnK918TqpPBAdj.P1O5uJAZgKEmLMZLSBEIWIEOUPTJaSvI3qxxk1ItXI_5sZDAQuw.86R3eaSIolGHqWTvpLk3WqnqBvtk6w6qIVcZgJrTFxnjx_x1ijJhKACcnY.jYp6kpxMihe8hOrTEyVj4Swhmq4RUWDhAfIQDNNju5dJCqW82QyYNCQdf0IMW7uIRSvHK1FmTGrEWMv4tpojLtJEf5vnKaDbrxZ0.AB9OSRwhzMkUYkgbiEVCwqyxCy_oEQBB0uVuAL8fOYidPrqv8m.A29j7S9d3Cb7DFh7pQJJGkLzljcC4VkEZADLiPnq_aLZuy0ehb_aTLBoHZ0IUL","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":"3600","refresh_token":"ABrQBFdlHzed4sc.aHygqG0faENua5L865UMVglio2hkbIJAnbY-"}"

'check1' is there and token value is result of `var_dump($resp);` but **'check2' not working.** 
So I think `$json = json_decode($resp);` is fail.

How do I decode this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get a error message? or do you can't access `$json['access_token']`, then you must add true to get a array back and not a object `$json = json_decode($resp, true);`

Comment: It should be `$json->access_token`

Comment: @PhillipBartschinski Hello, there is no anything error message. Just the result.

Comment: @aldrin27 Umm.. where do I `$json->access_token`? after `echo 'check2';`?

Comment: Yes. Just below the decoded data.

Comment: Yes after check2 and you have no output from `echo "check2 <br />";`?

Comment: @PhillipBartschinski Yes, no output from `echo "check2 <br />";` so I confuse... that seems mean `$json = json_decode($resp);` is fail.. But I think this code is just ok.

Comment: can you add in your php code at the top `error_reporting(-1);` then you get all error messages back and look in your php error log file also

Comment: Try json_last_error refer the link over here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php. This will give you idea if you have any error while decoding.

Comment: What is in your `$context`? I feel like this might be due to encoding issue. You should use `UTF-8` encoding. Also try to `trim` content before passing to `json_decode`

Comment: @andrew In the `$context`, http request using `stream_context_create()` that need to get OAuth access_token. And I try trim() but fail. I think json_decode have error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is encoding issue. You have [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your response that is not shown by `var_dump` but is not properly treated by `json_encode`.

If you try to do next:

```
$s = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".'{"access_token":"j9MqiEM.lKjepCGMFdKufPw1UBK_gAlG6qFxvMxHJwbopXfo9LpLUyT1z.YxwFBSydvVSMOqzVI4fX_ZVLVROlNf7ARr08s2tkFMb5_TNq.wp1MmoQm3wJaqF9gxpeQbEz4GYuGJSbDKJTw8LA_XoBNcE$

var_dump($s);
var_dump(json_decode($s));
```

You will get exact same result as in your response.

You can play around with headers to make sure that you are using `utf-8` encoding during request or you can get rid of `BOM` by:

```
$bomBinString = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
$s = preg_replace("/^$bomBinString/", '', $s);
```